# How to recover the deleted GKE cluster from GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, recover

What are the steps for recovering the deleted Google Kubernetes Engine cluster in Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: Just make a new one? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 3):

Once you delete it, it's gone. You can't recover it unless you backed it up.

There are a couple of popular tools to backup your cluster:

- [Ark](https://github.com/heptio/ark)
- [kube-backup](https://github.com/pieterlange/kube-backup)

If you have a stateful applications Ark is a better solution, since it handles things like [persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/). If you have stateless applications kube-backup is good enough since it basically backups all your Kubernetes cluster resources.

If you have stateful applications, i.e databases, it may also vary on a case by case basis, for example you'd backup a MySQL database with [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html).